# How is $C(n,r) = C(n-1, r-1) + C(n-1,r)$

Tags: combinations

How is  $C(n,r) = C(n-1, r-1) +  C(n-1,r)?$ I am watching P & C video from [here](https://youtu.be/Dsi7x-A89Mw?t=594)

I have read that suppose we have n distinct inputs. We have two possibilities:

1) Can select

2) Not select

If I select one from n then I am left with $C(n-1, r-1)$ and if I don't select I am left with $C(n-1, r)$.

I don't understand this $C(n-1, r)$ part. If I don't select how did the total elements turn $n-1$ shouldn't they still remain $n$. Any mathematical proof to prove the equality or understand it better?

Comment: If you don't select a given element, this means  $r$ elements will be chosen among the $n-1$ other elements.

Comment: @Bernard now I get it. I misunderstood the statement. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two proofs of [Pascal's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule).

**Algebraic Method:**
\begin{align*}
\binom{n - 1}{r - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{r} & = \frac{(n - 1)!}{(r - 1)![n - 1 - (r - 1)]!} + \frac{(n - 1)!}{r!(n - 1 - r)!}\\
& = \frac{(n - 1)!}{(r - 1)!(n - r)!} + \frac{(n - 1)!}{r!(n - r - 1)!}\\
& = \frac{(n - 1)!r}{(r - 1)!(n - r)!r} + \frac{(n - 1)!(n - r)}{r!(n - r - 1)!(n - r)}\\
& = \frac{(n - 1)!r}{r!(n - r)!} + \frac{(n - 1)!(n - r)}{r!(n - r)!}\\
& = \frac{(n - 1)!(r + n - r)}{r!(n - r)!}\\
& = \frac{(n - 1)!n}{r!(n - r)!}\\
& = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}\\
& = \binom{n}{r}
\end{align*}

**Combinatorial Method:**  A subset of $r$ elements can be selected from a set of $n$ elements in $$\binom{n}{r}$$ ways.  Suppose we wish to select $r$ elements from the set $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n - 1}, x_n\}$.  There are two possibilities.  The subset either contains the element $x_n$, or it does not.  If $x_n$ is one of the $r$ elements in the subset, we must select $x_n$ and $r - 1$ elements from the subset $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n - 1}\}$, which can be done in $$\binom{1}{1}\binom{n - 1}{r - 1} = \binom{n - 1}{r - 1}$$ ways.  If $x_n$ is not one of the $r$ elements in the subset, we must select $r$ elements from the subset $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n - 1}\}$, which can be done in $$\binom{n - 1}{r}$$ ways.  Hence, the number of ways of selecting $r$ elements from a set with $n$ elements is 
$$\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n - 1}{r - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{r}$$